# meta send vs. reload() | Server executed vs. client executed

Tags: php, javascript

Progam control is at the server and I need to do a relaod.  I can use a php command:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">'
```

or I can pass control back to the client with a reload flag set and use a javascript command

```
window.location.reload();
```

Which is best practice or better to use, in terms of speed?

My guess it that the PHP version would be a bit faster because there is no logic on the client side, the browser receives the header and reloads.

I'm not concerned with disabled javascript.

Comment: Jakob is totally right with his answer, but I think you should go with option 1. There is one (in my opinion important) question to ask yourself: What happens when Javascript is disabled? In case of optionb 2 -> nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm both examples here are **CLIENT SIDE**.

In example

1. You simply tell the document to refresh based on the `<META>` effectively the browser is aware of the refresh, PHP is just responsible for including the `<META>` for the document header. Cleaner way is to actually do `header( "refresh:0;url=wherever.php" );`
2. Here you simply reload it using `JAVASCRIPT`.

They both do the job. Speed doesn't matter as the refresh is based on your parameter (when to reload/refresh)

Comment: PHP is server side code and JavaScript is client side code.  I think the point you are making is that on PHP refresh...the page does not get send with the header...it is just a command telling it to do the refresh...technically control originates from the server for a PHP refresh..and control originates from the client on a JavaScript reload.

Comment: @TheAllFoo _technically_ all code that you send to the browser (including your JavaScript) originates from the server ;-) However, it's the browser that will reload in both cases, using two different instructions.

Comment: ...why I asked the question...was that if control is on the server side...and I want to do a reload...I can not just send the page...I have to send a command to the client...and then from there a page load is initiated...this seems to be in-efficient...if you are already at the server and you know you want to do a reload...why not just send the page?

Comment: @TheAllFoo, not sure what is in-efficient about communicating to the client about a redirect.  The client browses, the server directs, you cannot break that bond.  What you are outlining in your comment is NOT a redirect but new content, which might work to suit your needs just fine, its just not a redirect, as the user stays in the same 'space' just the content changes.

Comment: in Ajax you could just do a .innerHTML to the body tag to get the effect I speak of.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that the first option works if javascript is disabled, presumably.

Answer (score 2):

Both "meta refresh" and "window.location.reload()" via JavaScript are client side. The browser handles the refresh, and you're entirely at the mercy of the browser to implement it.

While the meta refresh method does not require JavaScript, you have less control over it. Via PHP, the HTML must be created at load time.

Via JavaScript, you could trigger the load at any time. You could even create a "meta refresh" header with JavaScript.

A reliable way might be to create the meta refresh header, but if JavaScript is enabled, delete the header via JavaScript and do the reloading when you really want via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It is my feeling that the php solution is better, but as I say it's more of a feeling than anything else.
My reasoning is:

You only have to have the logic in one place (rather than setting a flag and then checking it in the javascript).

You get to have cleaner javascript code.

If javascript is disabled, then it still works (if you care about that).

I would imagine that in modern browsers the difference in speed is negligable, but I have nothing to back that up.